# mouse movement slows game down

Tags: c#, winforms

i am developing a space invader game which has a mouse_move event. it works but when i move the mouse, everything slows down. the invaders and other things stop moving until you stop moving the mouse

Can someone please explain why and what can be done to resolve this.

thanx

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Dispose();
    objsp.gsPos = new Point(MousePosition.X / 2 - 10, MousePosition.Y / 2 - 15);

    UpdatePosition(objsp.gsPos.X, objsp.gsPos.Y, objsp.gsImage);
}

private void UpdatePosition(int dx, int dy, Image img)
{
    Point newPos = new Point(objsp.gsPos.X + dx, objsp.gsPos.Y + dy);

    //dont go out of window boundary
    newPos.X = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ClientSize.Width - img.Width, newPos.X));
    newPos.Y = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ClientSize.Height - img.Height, newPos.Y));

    if (newPos != objsp.gsPos)
    {
        objsp.gsPos = newPos;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you have in your `mouse_move` event handler.

Comment: post UpdatePosition's source please

Comment: thats the method. nothing else to it. its just being called in the mouse move event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably doing way too much work in your mouse_move handler.  Since you don't provide the code that's the best advice I can offer.

You have to be careful what you do in a handler like that.  Mouse move will get fired many, many times when dragging the mouse around.  You should do as little as possible in that event.

If you post your code we can help further, but until then we don't have enough info to give you a solid fix

EDIT:

Now that you've posted the code I see you are calling `Invalidate()` in *every mouse move event*.  You are constantly repainting the entire form.  That's a lot of work to be performing that often.  You need to be a bit more intelligent about what you redraw.

Try invalidating only the region that needs to be redrawn as a first step.  That should help things markedly.  `Invalidate()` will accept a `Rectangle` as an argument, use that.

Comment: @KuvenRamsamy: Added some info.

Comment: thanx. i am new to game programming. would you please explain on how i  go about doing that invalidate() method

Comment: @KuvenRamsamy: Can you post your `OnPaint` method for me?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try not to run the code everytime the event fires. Maybe restrict it to only run the code on every 5th event fire or once every 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a variety of reasons that this could happen and without seeing the code it is hard to tell which one it could be.

The most common cause of this is that the event handler is taking over the execution and causing everything to wait on it. Solutions usually mean making your code more efficient.

Comment: i put the code above. as you can see its 3 lines and the updateposition method